# Why did rtorrent fail to build?

Tags: centos, build, rtorrent, autoconf, autotools

**I am not root**, so I have to build rtorrent from source and hope to install it in my home directory, but it failed, why?

```
[mirror@hugemeow rtorrent]$ ls
AUTHORS  autogen.sh  ChangeLog  configure.ac  COPYING  doc  INSTALL  Makefile.am  NEWS  rak  README  scripts  src  test
[mirror@hugemeow rtorrent]$ ./autogen.sh
aclocal...
aclocal:configure.ac:7: warning: macro `AM_PATH_CPPUNIT' not found in library
autoheader...
libtoolize... using libtoolize
automake...
configure.ac: installing `./install-sh'
configure.ac: installing `./missing'
src/Makefile.am: installing `./depcomp'
autoconf...
configure.ac:7: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_PATH_CPPUNIT
      If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
      See the Autoconf documentation.
```

Though autoge failed, configure script is created.

```
[mirror@hugemeow rtorrent]$ ls
aclocal.m4  autogen.sh      ChangeLog     config.h.in  configure     COPYING  doc      install-sh  Makefile.am  missing  rak     scripts  test
AUTHORS     autom4te.cache  config.guess  config.sub   configure.ac  depcomp  INSTALL  ltmain.sh   Makefile.in  NEWS     README  src
```

Ran `configure`, and failed for **syntax error near unexpected token `1.9.6'**, what's wrong? What should I do in order to build this rtorrent for my CentOS?

```
[mirror@hugemeow rtorrent]$ ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
./configure: line 2016: syntax error near unexpected token `1.9.6'
./configure: line 2016: `AM_PATH_CPPUNIT(1.9.6)'
[mirror@hugemeow rtorrent]$ git branch
* master
[mirror@hugemeow rtorrent]$ git branch  -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/c++11
  remotes/origin/master
[mirror@hugemeow rtorrent]$ git tag
0.9.0
0.9.1
[mirror@hugemeow rtorrent]$ git clean -dfx
Removing Makefile.in
Removing aclocal.m4
Removing autom4te.cache/
Removing config.guess
Removing config.h.in
Removing config.log
Removing config.sub
Removing configure
Removing depcomp
Removing doc/Makefile.in
Removing install-sh
Removing ltmain.sh
Removing missing
Removing src/Makefile.in
Removing src/core/Makefile.in
Removing src/display/Makefile.in
Removing src/input/Makefile.in
Removing src/rpc/Makefile.in
Removing src/ui/Makefile.in
Removing src/utils/Makefile.in
Removing test/Makefile.in
```

**Edit 1**: Details about libtool and libtools

```
[mirror@hugemeow rtorrent]$ libtoolize --version
libtoolize (GNU libtool) 1.5.22

Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
[mirror@hugemeow rtorrent]$ libtool --version
ltmain.sh (GNU libtool) 1.5.22 (1.1220.2.365 2005/12/18 22:14:06)

Copyright (C) 2005  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: hugemeow, please take care of proper capitalization in your title, it should go "Why did building … fail?" or "Why can't I build …".

Answer (score 7):

Just went into the same issue, and as @mikio-tsunematsu pointed out as a comment, the solution is to install `libcppunit` and `libcppunit-dev` (or `cppunit` and `cppunit-devel`). As you say you can't install them using package manager, then your only solution is to get the sources and compile them in your directory.

You usually can download sources of packages of your distribution and compile them using it, which may help work with the installed tools on your system.

as it worked for me, HTH

Comment: installing cppunit and cppunit-devel fixed it on cygwin :)

Answer (score 2):

That syntax error hints that the ./configure failed. Do you have *libtool* installed/up to date?

Comment: see edit 1 for details, i am not sure whether my libtool is up to date...

Comment: Just had a thought - try and _yum install cppunit cppunit-devel_ if you haven't already and then try ./configure again.

Comment: the issue is that i am not root, and that admin may do nothing for me, so i have to do all the things in my home directory...

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're missing some dependencies to compile _libtorrent_. You might be able to find a way around with _schroot_ and work in there, but I can't promise it'll work.

Comment: should i follow http://le-gall.net/sylvain+violaine/blog/index.php?post/2010/08/26/63-centos-5-chroot-with-schroot ?  i think this is quite difficult and error prone ...

Answer (score 0):

Just edit `configure.ac` and remove the `AM_PATH_CPPUNIT(1.9.6)` line, after which `autogen.sh` should generate a `configure` that doesn't error out.